# Javascript cannot split string

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am trying to split the word google and and store it as array element but it is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <p>
    Click "Try it" to display the first array element, after a string split.    
  </p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var str = "google";
        var arr = str.split("");
        var txt = arr[0];
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr[0];
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Function is not closed. Check console, you should get an error.

Comment: That's just about the worst title I've seen yet. It says absolutely zero about what problem you need help with.

Comment: look in browser console at errors thrown. If you used proper indentation would have better chance of spotting errors also

Comment: Thank you all for helping me, I closed the function it is working..

Answer (score 0):

Works as intended...

```js
function myFunction() {
        var str = "google";
        var arr = str.split("");
        var txt = arr[0]; //Why are you setting this
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr[0]; //if you're not using that variable anyway
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Though I don't get why you'd split `""`.

Comment: I am learning javascript. and thankyou very much for spending your time for helping me

Comment: @vSugumar Alright no problem, good luck. Close your function and it should run fine.